# some modules could not be import on jupyter notebook after installed from miniforge

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I got some error like `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'` on apple silicon MacBook Pro. Since some modules can not install on MacBook by `pip`, then I used miniforge and conda successfully to install numpy, mathplot and pandas. However, those modules could be imported on jupyter notebook.

Any suggestions for solving this?

Comment: Try `!pip install numpy` in your jupyter notebook?

Comment: no still same error